# Cannot access Mac via SMB

Tags: high-sierra, smb

I have fired up an old notebook running Windows XP (to use some legacy software). This has network access via a local router (all machines connect to the same router).

I am attempting to network this, and have tried a number of things, unsuccessfully.

I have setup a home or office network and can ping and see my wife's MacBook (running 10.13) but not connect.

On my iMac I have enabled File Sharing via AFP and SMB and set my home directory as shared. The iMac Firewall allows incoming File Sharing (AFP, SMB)

Unfortunately the Windows machine can not see my iMac, although it does resolve the IP using `COMPUTER.local`

Presumably there is some other setting which differs between my wife's MacBook and my iMac.

I also tried accessing the iMac via FTP (unsuccessfully), although this is probably a separate issue.

Can anyone suggest what I should do to enable SMB?

Comment: If you cannot ping your Mac from your XP notebook, you're not going to x-fer anything with any protocol.  Your best start is to get the networking info of both machines and verify that they can ping the router/gateway.  If both have network connectivity, start looking at firewalls.  However, at this stage of the game, I am fairly confident that one or both of your computers aren't properly connected.

Comment: @Allan I had "stealth mode" on the iMac, now off, but still can't see SMB